# How to proxy pass for another website (reverse proxy) in istio like we do in nginx https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Tags: nginx, istio, istio-gateway

I have to do a similar type of thing in istio

```
location /some/path/ {
proxy_pass http://www.example.com/link/;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be possible with using ServiceEntry with TCP protocol bypass filters because of the proxy simply acts as a TCP tunnel. Look for the [documentation example](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/http-proxy/). It is very well described how to use an External HTTPS Proxy.

See also:

- [all about ingress in istio](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/)
- [similar question on github](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/23298)
- [similar question on discuss.istio.io](https://discuss.istio.io/t/is-it-possible-to-use-istio-as-a-reverse-proxy-similar-to-nginx-proxy-pass/6319)